# Extend class in same module with class methods defined in module

Tags: ruby

I have a module with some class methods I'd like to make available to classes within the module. However, what I'm doing is not working.

```
module Foo
  class << self
    def test
      # this method should be available to subclasses of module Foo
      # this method should be able to reference subclass constants and methods
      p 'test'
    end
  end
end

class Foo::Bar
  extend Foo
end
```

This fails:

```
Foo::Bar.test
NoMethodError: undefined method `test'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Foo::Bar::ActivityCreator` - is there a class definition missing from your example code?

Comment: ActivityCreator was an error - try extend Foo instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you `extend` a module from a class, the module's instance methods become class methods in the class. So you need:

```
module Foo
  def test
    puts "hi"
  end
end

class Foo::Bar
  extend Foo
end

Foo::Bar.test #=> hi
```

If you'd also like to have a module method `Foo::test`, which can be called from anywhere with `Foo.test`, change the above to:

```
module Foo
  def test
    puts "hi"
  end
  extend self
end

Foo::Bar.test #=> hi
Foo.test      #=> "hi"
```